# How to detect system accent color in background task on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to know current system accent color in background task?

I need this color value for my tiles.

thanks~

Comment: The easiest way is to use a Transparent color, imho.

Comment: If you use it for your tiles, you should use Transparent. Otherwise your tiles will not change, when the user changes his accentcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```cs
var color = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
```